# Difference b/w Filesystem I/O (__GFP_FS) and Disk I/O (__GFP_IO)

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

**May i know in linux kernel what is the difference between filesystem I/O (GFP_FS) and Disk I/O (GFP_IO)?**

Answer (score 2):

It is plain and simple that filesystem I/O is I/O happening on the filesystem. Lets say you are reading/writing on a file which is represented on the filesystem. The disk IO is the IO happening directly on the disk. This is block IO. On a layering standpoint you can say, the disk IO happens at a low level than the file system IO. And you can even say, the filesystem IO *may* get translated to disk IO.

It may also worth notable that the filesystem io may happen without an associated disk IO on cached data/files or for a filesystem which is not backed up by a disk. Say, a ramdisk filesystem, ofcourse the /proc/ filesystem.